# Docker - Run Wildfly standalone

Tags: java, docker, wildfly

I have a Ubuntu server with a WildFly standalone installation configured, here i have a Java app that is accesible on port 80, i want to dockerize it. When create the container, i'm copying the entire WildFly directory from my local storage to the container, when i run the command `docker run -d --name dej_website -p 80:80 wildfly_dej_website:2.0` the container start, but when try to access in my local machine `localhost` doesn't works.

What am i doing wrong? How can i do to access to this container, with the configured server?

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM centos

#INSTALL JAVA
RUN yum -y install java-11-openjdk
RUN java -version

RUN mkdir /opt/DEJ_Wildfly/

#SET OPT AS WORK DIRECTORY
WORKDIR /opt/DEJ_Wildfly/

#COPY WILDFLY SERVER FILES
COPY wildfly-11.0.0.Final .

#DEFINE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE
ENV JBOSS_HOME /opt/DEJ_Wildfly/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/

#EXECUTE SH FILE
CMD JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0
CMD tail -f /var/log/lastlog
#EXPOSE 80
```

This is the log of `docker build --tag wildfly_dej_website:2.0 .` command:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  597.4MB
Step 1/9 : FROM centos
---> 300e315adb2f
Step 2/9 : RUN yum -y install java-11-openjdk
---> Using cache
---> f333f6149e02
Step 3/9 : RUN java -version
---> Using cache
---> 0110143899c7
Step 4/9 : RUN mkdir /opt/DEJ_Wildfly/
---> Running in 88bc6f0632c1
Removing intermediate container 88bc6f0632c1
---> c0ab7cc8a364
Step 5/9 : WORKDIR /opt/DEJ_Wildfly/
---> Running in 84705355ac2c
Removing intermediate container 84705355ac2c
---> 6986f8229cb0
Step 6/9 : COPY wildfly-11.0.0.Final .
---> 3caf8ec0e5d0
Step 7/9 : ENV JBOSS_HOME /opt/DEJ_Wildfly/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/
---> Running in b5f649e4e2e0
Removing intermediate container b5f649e4e2e0
---> 27d775c3d0cb
Step 8/9 : CMD JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0
---> Running in c7ffddb4bcdf
Removing intermediate container c7ffddb4bcdf
---> 533d3836f94d
Step 9/9 : CMD tail -f /var/log/lastlog
---> Running in f92aca5a63ba
Removing intermediate container f92aca5a63ba
---> 974e6ec6c415
Successfully built 974e6ec6c415
Successfully tagged wildfly_dej_website:2.0
```

This is the list of containers:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                CREATED       STATUS       PORTS              NAMES
95ee0139f42c   wildfly_dej_website:2.0 "/bin/sh -c 'tail -f…" 4 seconds ago Up 2 seconds 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp dej_website
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is in your dockerfile.

You need to add a `CMD` at the end of your dockerfile to run the command you want and keep it running for the docker file to stay alive and provide you with logs through `docker logs` command.

Add a line like this to your dockerfile:

```
RUN ./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0
CMD tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

And to make the port accessible on the local machine you'll need to use `-p` option when issuing the `docker run` command like this:

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080 <image>
```

you can find out more here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: i added this line, but when i try to create the container  `docker run -d --name dej_website -p 80:80 wildfly_dej_website:2.0` the status of container is exited and don't change the status to up

Comment: Try `CMD $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0` to make sure it runs try to set the location for `$JBOSS_HOME` in an `ENV` tag in your dockerfile. like this `ENV /address/to/jboss_home`.
also
if `standalone.sh` runs in the background as a daemon then try adding it to a `RUN` tag and then for the `CMD` use something like this: `CMD tail -f /var/log/lastlog`

Comment: I updated the question and i follow this steps and with this the container run ok, but when i try to access in my local machine to `localhost` doesn't work, how can i access it?

Comment: I've updated the answer based on the updates